# nerdtree: not allowed to enter a popup window

Tags: plugin-nerdtree

I'm using Vim8.2 with the plugin Nerdtree and some other plugins to work with Golang.

Here is how I configure my vim: https://github.com/YvesZHI/Giraffa-vim

All of configs can be found in the file `vimrc` and the file `Giraffa.vim`.

I got such a problem:

When I enter my Vim, open a file from Nerdtree, it works fine. But sometimes, when I `:q` to quit a file and try to open another file from Nerdtree, I may get an error:

```
Error detected while processing function nerdtree#ui_glue#invokeKeyMap[1]..79[18]..78[3]..<SNR>31_customOpenFile[1]..108[1]..124[3]..180[6]..181[9]..175[19]..183[2].
.178[23]..nerdtree#exec[9]..function nerdtree#ui_glue#invokeKeyMap[1]..79[18]..78[3]..<SNR>31_customOpenFile[1]..108[1]..124[3]..180[6]..181[9]..175[19]..183[2]..178
[23]..nerdtree#exec:
line    6:
E366: Not allowed to enter a popup window
Error detected while processing function nerdtree#ui_glue#invokeKeyMap[1]..79[18]..78[3]..<SNR>31_customOpenFile[1]..108[1]..124[3]..180[6]..181[9]..175[19]..183[2].
.178:
line   23:
E171: Missing :endif
Error detected while processing function nerdtree#ui_glue#invokeKeyMap[1]..79[18]..78[3]..<SNR>31_customOpenFile[1]..108[1]..124[3]..180[6]..181[9]..175[19]..183:
line    2:
E171: Missing :endif
Error detected while processing function nerdtree#ui_glue#invokeKeyMap[1]..79[18]..78[3]..<SNR>31_customOpenFile[1]..108[1]..124[3]..180[6]..181[9]..175:
line   19:
E171: Missing :endif
Error detected while processing function nerdtree#ui_glue#invokeKeyMap[1]..79[18]..78:
line    3:
E171: Missing :endif
Error detected while processing function nerdtree#ui_glue#invokeKeyMap[1]..79:
line   18:
E171: Missing :endif
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

It seems that there is some popup window, which blocks me from opening a file from Nerdtree.

But I can't see any popup window.

[image]

One way to solve this issue without quitting my Vim is to execute the command `:call popup_clear()`.

I've google a lot but haven't found any helpful infomation.

How could I figure out where the popup window comes from? How to solve this problem?

Comment: Create an issue at the plugin upstream repository?

Comment: Which go plugins ? Martin’s is the only one I know of that uses popups, and even then sparingly.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble In fact it's not about go plugins. Because I have another group of plugins, which is used to code C++, and I have the same issue.